# Querying MySQL tables using Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb

I am trying to use Kafka Streams for achieving a use-case.
I have two tables in MySQL - User and Account. And I am getting events from MySQL into Kafka using a Kafka MySQL connector.

I need to get all user-IDs within an account from within Kafka itself. 
So I was planning to use **KStream** on MySQL output topic, process it to form an output and publish it to a topic with Key as the account-id and value as the userIds separated by comma (,). 
Then I can use **interactive query** to get all userIds using account id, with the **get()** method of **ReadOnlyKeyValueStore** class.
Is this the right way to do this? Is there a better way?
Can KSQL be used here?

Comment: Can you summarise what it is you're wanting to do with this data? I understand that you have the two tables in MySQL, and you want to bring them into Kafka - and do what with them from there? i.e. can you describe the requirement?

Comment: I have a real-time streaming application wrote with Kafka streams, which needs this data. Making an HTTP call or retrieving data from MySql is going to be time-consuming. So it is better to have all the data in Kafka itself in a queryable form.

Comment: Using "Interactive Queries" with KSQL is not possible atm.

Comment: If I have a table 'user_details' in MySql, which is brought into Kafka using Debezum. If I want to execute a query like get all users in account abc, is this possible using State store and KTable?

Comment: I guess if you use a CDC approach and have a KTable updated with the latest data for your entities (i.e: account), you could enrich your KStream (i.e: users) with account information and perform your logics from there.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Kafka Connect to stream data in from MySQL, e.g. using [Debezium](http://debezium.io/). From here you can use KStreams, or KSQL, to transform the data, including re-keying which I think is what you're looking to do here, as well as join it to other streams. 
If you ingest the data from MySQL into a topic with log compaction set then you are guaranteed to always have the latest value for every key in the topic.

Comment: I was trying to use Kstreams for achieving my use case. Here transform output should be a key-value pair where the key is the account id and value the user ids separated by a comma. KStream is consuming the debezium user table topic. The issue I face is, I need to append a new userId to the existing string on each insert event. I need to access the output topic for getting the existing string. Should I use state store for accessing the output topic from inside the 'stream.map()' method?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at striim if you want built in CDC and interactive continuous SQL queries on the streaming data in one UI. More info here:

http://www.striim.com/blog/2017/08/making-apache-kafka-processing-preparation-kafka/